# Problem when printing data from an object array, it appears incorrectly

Tags: javascript

I have this program where there are a series of registered students and when they put their name, their data and the name of the teacher they have assigned.
When inserting a new student, the only thing that it does to me correctly is to print if the teacher exists or not, since the student's data does not show them to me, and finally I have a failure in the last line of the javascript code related to innerhtml , the error in question is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting
> 'innerHTML')
> at mensaje.js:74

now the code:

html:

```
 <button onclick="infoalumno()">Informacion del alumno</button>
    <button onclick="insertar()">Introducir nuevo alumno</button>
    <div id="info"></div>
```

and javascript code:

```
function alumno(nombre, edad, nota, profesor) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.nota = nota;
    this.profesor = profesor;
}

function profesor(nombre, asginatura) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.asginatura = asginatura;
}

var profesores = new Array(3);
profesores[0] = new profesor("Paco","Plastica");
profesores[1] = new profesor("Anton","Biologia");
profesores[2] = new profesor("Jacinto","Lengua");

var alumnos = new Array(2);
alumnos[0] = new alumno("Jose",24,7,profesores[0]);
alumnos[1] = new alumno("Jacobo",23,7,profesores[2]);


function infoalumno() {

    var buscar = prompt("Inserta el nombre del alumno que quieres buscar");

    var comprobar = false
    for (let i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {
        if (buscar == alumnos[i].nombre) {
            document.write("Nombre" + alumnos[i].nombre + "<br>Edad:" + alumnos[i].edad + "<br>Nota:" + alumnos[i].nota + "<br>Profesor:" + alumnos[i].profesor.nombre);
            comprobar = true;
        }
        if (comprobar == false) {
            document.write("Alumno " + buscar + "no existe");
        }
    }
}


function insertar() {

    var comprobar2 = false;

    var nombre = prompt("Insertar el nombre del alumno");
    var edad = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa la edad"));
    var nota = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa la nota"));
    var profesor = prompt("¿Quien es el profesor?");
    for (let i = 0; i < profesores.length; i++) {
        if (profesor == profesores[i].nombre) {
            var newalumno = new alumno(nombre, edad, nota, profesor[i]);
            alumnos.push(newalumno);
            comprobar2=true;
            break;//la sentencia break permite terminar de forma abrupta un bucle y la sentencia continue permite saltarse algunas repeticiones del bucle. ... La utilidad de break es terminar la ejecución del bucle cuando una variable toma un determinado valor o cuando se cumple alguna condición.
        }
    }

    if(comprobar2==false){
        document.write("Profesor "+profesor+" no existe");
    }

   

}


var infoprofesor ="Profesores";
for (let i = 0; i < profesores.length; i++) {
   infoprofesor = infoprofesor + profesores[i].nombre+"<br>";
    
}

document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = infoprofesor;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)**

> The teacher does not appear his name instead appears [object Object]

In this code

```
document.write("Nombre" + alumnos[i].nombre + "<br>Edad:" + alumnos[i].edad + "<br>Nota:" + alumnos[i].nota + "<br>Profesor:" + alumnos[i].profesor);
```

This `alumnos[i].profesor` will be a `Profesor` object like from calling `new Profesor(...)`. If you wanted to show the name it would look like `alumnos[i].profesor.nombre`

**2)**

> And when inserting a new student, the only thing that it does to me
> correctly is to print if the teacher exists or not.

```
var profesor = prompt("¿Quien es el profesor?");    
for (let i = 0; i < profesores.length; i++) {
    if (profesor == profesores[i].nombre) {
        var newalumno = new alumno(nombre, edad, nota, profesor);
        alumnos.push(newalumno);
        comprobar2=true;
        break;
    }
}
```

In this loop you have a related issue. The result from prompt will just be a string (your `var profesor`). However when you go to make your new `alumno` it expects a `profesor` object (with nombre/asignatura).

In this case you're probably want to do `var newalumno = new alumno(nombre, edad, nota, profesores[i]);`

Comment: thanks, i fix one of the mistakes of my program, but I still can't print the new students that I add and I still have problems with the innerhtml